# Silverlight control cannot receive input focus when switch to another window and then switch back

Tags: c#, silverlight, textbox, window, focus

In my silverlight application, there are several textbox to receive input, when i switch to another window, then switch back to the browser window, sometimes the textbox can not get the input focus. Anyone know what caused this strange problem?

When i switch back to the browser window, although i click the textbox, it will automatically loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

Try set TabIndex of textbox to "0".